# Using Fixed point in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

In my filter design , I am using fixed point arithmetic and using sfixed for signals. The design synthesizes with all timing met but my functional simulation and post synth/P&R simulation do not match after arith logic blocks.. Giving a small ex below, where I see that crf_int_r does not match in Post synth simulation.. Can someone help me understand , whether it is not synthesized properly or some other issue for a mismatch between functional and post synth simulation..Using Xilinx ISE 14.7 and VHDL 200X option in ISE.

```
signal add_alpha1_r : sfixed(5 downto -13) ;
signal add_alpha2_r : sfixed(6 downto -13) ;
signal crf_r : sfixed(17 downto -13) ;
signal crf_int_r : sfixed(17 downto -7) ; 
signal alpha_log : sfixed(4 downto -13) ;
signal imgdel_r_d4 : sfixed(4 downto -13) ;
signal imgsum_d2 : sfixed(4 downto -13) ; 

  add_alpha1_r <= imgdel_r_d4 - imgsum_d2  ; --19.13   
  add_alpha2_r <= alpha_log + add_alpha1_r  ; -- 20.13  
  crf_r      <= add_alpha2_r * beta ; -- 31.13   
  crf_int_r    <= crf_r(17 downto -7);
```

Comment: Declarations, pre and post synthesis operand and result binary values would be nice. Are you using non-default package generics?

Comment: I am using ieee fixed point pkg's.                                                                      use ieee_proposed.fixed_float_types.all;

Comment: In post synth netlist , some signals are generated with declaration as std_logic_vector(5 downto -3). Such signals give error in VCOM. And I am changing such signals to type std_logic_vector1 as per info from xilinx. But still I get a mismatch , though I see multipliers have been inferred..

Comment: Who's simulator? The reason I ask is the cfr_r assignment get's a bound check failure with -2008 instantiated package ieee.fixed_generic_pkg. Please add new information to your question. You missed beta declaration, I set it to the same as add_alpha2_r. Binary operand and result values?

Comment: I am using Modelsim 10.1c with VHDL=2002 option set. In Xilinx i have VHDL=200X set.. I am using ieee libraries                                                 use ieee_proposed.fixed_float_types.all;
use ieee_proposed.fixed_pkg.all ;                                                                    I am converting crf_int_r to integer and comparing to Matlab generated files.. But Post P&R output is all -ve no's . I see DSP being instantiated , so not able to figure whats getting wrong in Post synthesis/P&R..

Comment: constant beta                  : sfixed(10 downto 0) := "00000111100";

Comment: You need to write a proper question. Show the code with all the declarations, provide a set of inputs and the corresponding outputs, and tell us how the output is different from your expected output. If the output is correct in functional sims and incorrect in post-P&R then tell us exactly what the difference is. "converting to integer and comparing to Matlab" and "all -ve" is no use to anybody.

Comment: My  basic questions is : In above Code, "crf_int_r"  value  in functional and post synth simulations values are not same?                                                     constant beta                  : sfixed(10 downto 0) := "00000111100";                  signal alpha_log               : sfixed(4 downto -13) ;
signal imgsum_d2               : sfixed(4 downto -13) ;
signal imgdel_r_d4             : sfixed(4 downto -13) ;

Comment: Your question isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), comments aren't part of the question, can be trimmed later. You haven't supplied enough information to duplicate the problem. Without operand and result values differing pre and post synthesis and seeing at least that part of post synthesis model involved in the multiply operator it may be impossible to provide further insight.  With your supplied beta declaration your crf_r assignment statement simulates without semantic errors.

Comment: I am able to find the root cause of problem now. I compared each signal in equation between post synth and pre synth to zero down the cause.               In Line ->add_alpha2_r <= alpha_log + add_alpha1_r  ; -- 20.13           alpha_log was evaluated to '0' in post synth.  While alpha is a constant declared as--> sfixed(10 downto 0) ="00001111000".. aplha_log is calculated as                               alpha_log <=  rom1log10((to_integer(alpha)); here rom1log10 is a table defined in a pkg with sfixed no's..alpha_log  was '0' in post synth. Don't know Why synth eval it as zero.. Thanks

Comment: I have redeclared alpha as constant of type integer now instead of sfixed. But Why to_integer(sfixed) conversion is not working in synthesis , i still don't understand..

Answer (score 1):

You encountered a synthesis bug. Making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from the code presented in the comments, I have tried to synthesize this with ISE 14.7 and VHDL-200X option on:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library ieee_proposed;
use ieee_proposed.fixed_pkg.all;

entity sfixed_test is
  port (alpha_log : out sfixed(4 downto -13));
end sfixed_test;

architecture rtl of sfixed_test is
  constant alpha : sfixed(10 downto 0) := "00001111000"; -- 120
  type rom_t is array(0 to 2047) of sfixed(4 downto -13);
  constant alpha_rom : rom_t := (120 => "111111111111111111",
                                 others => "000000000000000000");
begin  -- rtl
  alpha_log <= alpha_rom(to_integer(alpha));
end rtl;
```

XST reports the following warning:

> Warning: "::fixed_pkg:TO_INTEGER (sfixed): metavalue detected, returning 0"

A quick look into the RTL or Technology Map Viewer shows, that all outputs were connected to ground instead of VCC as intended in my example.

The problem is the implementation of `to_integer` as described bewlow. You can work around this, if you change the reading from the ROM to:

```
alpha_log <= alpha_rom(to_integer(unsigned(std_logic_vector(alpha))));
```

and also include the package `ieee.numeric_std`. Then everything works fine.

**Further notes:** The warning message refers to line 5085 ff. of `ieee_proposed/fixed_pkg_c.vhd` shipped with ISE. It reads:

```
if (Is_X (arg)) then
  assert NO_WARNING
    report fixed_pkg'instance_name
    & "TO_INTEGER (sfixed): metavalue detected, returning 0"
    severity warning;
  return 0;
end if;
```

`Is_X(arg)` checks whether the argument contains a `U`, `X`, `Z`, `W`, or `-`. It fails here if `arg` (which is `alpha`) is a constant. But, it works when `alpha` is a signal (input).